# Master page break when setting IIS Permissions

Tags: master-page, custom-masterpage, user-controls, http-module

While trying to set Permission to a site through IIS Console Manager, I notice that When someone jump into the web site, some Master controls break out.

[image]

[image]

If I remove the Security setting, everything it's Ok.

[image]

Has it something to do with http Module?

Answer (score 1):

You should use SharePoint Permission page for setting permission.

If users are part of Style Resource Readers group then these styles issues will not arise.

I would recommend you don't change settings in IIS and use Site Settings -> People & Group for grading permissions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I cannot user permission groups of SP, because it must remains a PROD twin copy!  Even groups settings and permissions . Is there any other way to manager permissions only for Admins by SP tools keeping the seetings?